# No such file or directory Error when trying to install fcntl using pip?

Tags: installation, pip, fcntl

I'm trying to install fcntl with pip and I entered this into cmd:

```
pip install pycopy-fcntl
```

However, this error pops up and I have no idea what it is or how to fix it:

```
Collecting pycopy-fcntl
Using cached pycopy-fcntl-0.0.4.tar.gz (868 bytes)
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\jackson\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, 
setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Jackson\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-l2eoh603\\pycopy-fcntl\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Jackson\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-l2eoh603\\pycopy-fcntl\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Jackson\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-j3akvbte'
     cwd: C:\Users\Jackson\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l2eoh603\pycopy-fcntl\
Complete output (5 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\jackson\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\tokenize.py", line 392, in open
    buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'C:\\Users\\Jackson\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-l2eoh603\\pycopy-fcntl\\setup.py'
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full 
command output.
```

Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The home page at https://github.com/pfalcon/pycopy-lib#readme says:

> pycopy-lib is a project to develop a non-monolithic standard library for the Pycopy project

It's not a `pip`-installable library, it's not even Python library at all. It's a library for Pycopy which is (https://github.com/pfalcon/pycopy#readme):

> Pycopy aims to develop and maintain a **minimalist**, lightweight, and extensible implementation of Python(-compatible) language.

What are you really trying to install? Module `fcntl`? It's a module from stdlib since the dawn of time: https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/fcntl.html

Comment: I'm trying to install it as part of a neutral network's dependencies when I got an error saying it cannot find the module. I am trying to test out this neural network that I got off GitHub.

Comment: @Jackson I doubt that `pycopy-fcntl` is what you're looking for. Rather verify that your installation of Python is built with `fcntl` — it's a module written in C and must be compiled.